# Even if I get a remote notification, not wake up my app that isn't running when other apps are in the foreground. Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

MyApp: Terminate or Suspended ( Not exist in App Swithcer)
OtherApp: Foreground

this situation.

Notification is received. However, this didReceiveRemoteNotification method is not invoked. (The app didn't wake up)
But, method in UNNotificationServiceExtension is called.
In other words, the appdelegate of my app is not executed.

If there are no other apps in Foreground, it runs well. (didReceiveRemoteNotification method)

Why is it like this?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to follow your question. Are you saying that your app has been force-quit? In that case you will not receive `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. This is [documented behavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application#):

> However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I've read the official document several times.

Comment: As you said, it's when you force-quit the app, but if another app is not in foreground, for example, when the home screen is still there, didReceiveRemoteNotification is called well. But didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called if another app is in this foreground.

Comment: OK; that's an interesting loophole. You can post a full example that demonstrates this (I haven't seen it before, and I suspect it may be an artifact of exactly how you're testing it). And you'd want to include the particular OS, since of course it may just be an artifact of Apple's implementation, and it would be an interesting anomaly. But it doesn't change anything. There is no "why" here other than "that's what this specific version of the OS does in this specific case." It is clearly not promised behavior that the app gets launched in this case. Apps get more than promised all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But I have a question.
Connect the device directly to the console of MacBook and check it, the app will run completely from AppDelegate when the app is turned off (maybe to call didReceiveRemoteNotification method). (Notification is received.)
Originally Is this right?

Comment: But I don't know how to look at the console when other apps are on top, but Springboard seemed to stop the backtask.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "is this right." If it's what iOS does, it's what iOS does (for this specific version). The docs are clear that you cannot expect to have the app launched if it was force-quit. That doesn't mean it promises never to launch the app. Your description of what you're doing is very vague, so I can't reproduce this. But even if I did, it wouldn't change anything. "In some cases, on some versions of iOS, a force-quit app may be launched when it wasn't promised." Maybe that's true. It could be a bug, implementation detail, or something quirky about how you're testing.